# generating a report for all orders with all information expresso store

Tags: expresso-store

I have one product with several modifiers. You can either pay offline for this product or pay online through paypal. I'm capturing various data from the form that the user fills in. Now I want to pull a report on **all** the orders that have been processed so far with **all** the details, such as product sku, customer name, address etc.

My problem is when I try to pull a report using 'orders report', it only shows those orders which have been **paid**. How do I show all orders no matter if they were paid or not?

Thanks

Comment: When your users pay "offline" you are using the manual payment method, right? The orders still show up with a "New" payment status?

Comment: yes, it's a manual payment method and the status is 'new' for each order.

Comment: That report should be showing all orders, paid or not. I'll look into this. In any case, if the built in reports aren't flexible enough for you, we recommend generating your own reports using the orders tag. So it might be a better option just to create your own custom report anyway?

Comment: I also would have thought it should be generating reports whether paid or not. Let me know if resolve this issue. If you need any more details let me know. I'm reluctant to do any more template work as I will have to charge for it and I thought I would be able to generate this type of report out of the box. Cheers

Comment: In the end I used the orders tag to generate a report and was able to displaey all the fields exactly how I wanted them. It's not ideal though as I needed to create a template and show the results in the frontend rather than the backend. Let me know if there was a better way of accomplishing this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The orders report should show all "completed" orders, regardless of whether they are paid or not.

If the built in reports aren't flexible enough for you, you can generate your own reports using the orders tag. So it might be a good idea just to create your own custom report.